# What is the function of a minus sign in fron of a variable definition in PHP?

Tags: php

I was looking at some PHP code:

```
<?php

-$username = "admin";
-$password = "secret";
-$database = "mystore";

mysql_connect("localhost", $username, $password);
mysql_select_db($database);
```

What is the function of the minus-sign in front of the variable names?

If I do the same in the PHP interpreter, it results in valid code and there seems to be no difference:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $a=1;echo $a;
1
php > -$a=2;echo $a;
2
```

I asked Google but she couldn't help me.

Comment: @Dagon Me too, pretty little symbols aren't they

Comment: This is will be hot post.

Comment: ps dont use this code mysql_* is depreciated

Comment: you now must trace down the original coder and ask him\her detailed questions.

Comment: @Dagon The author has long since gone. As part of the project, the author also wrote some Objective-C code. As I was told by a colleague, in Objective-C a plus or minus sign in front of statement does have a function. So, maybe he copied some code over from Objective-C to PHP, or he accidentally added the minus-signs, thinking it was Objective-C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-$username = "admin";` is evaluated as `- ($username = "admin");`

That is, a prefix unary operator `-` applied to the expression.

The expression consists of an assignment only.

So a string is assigned to a variable, then as per php syntax the expression returns the same value which is implicitly converted to a number and negated. Then the result is thrown away.

So there is no special meaning here, someone put it there accidentally.