# Why are the operators minus (hyphen) and plus valid almost anywhere in the code?

Tags: php

There is this answer which seems similar, https://stackoverflow.com/a/29958212/5542121
But it does not explain to me why this is valid - from php 4.3.0 - 7.4.2:

So far I see that those are not "tokens", https://www.php.net/manual/en/tokens.php
But there is nowhere an explanation for this behaviour.

https://3v4l.org/3V2jD

```
-

- 

$c = 5;

$a = 4; 
$b = -

- +  
$a = 4;
echo $b;
```

Output is  `4`

Comment: Well not _anywhere_ - if you made that `-[\n]-[\n]echo …` to begin with, you’d have a parse error.

Comment: I think this is essentially just the Identity and Negation operators in play here, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php - and no one says, you can’t perform multiple such “operations” chained.

Comment: Why should you **not** be able to negate a variable?

Comment: thx for comments, made me realize its just basic maths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, that those are operators, and are executed as such.

the code:

```php
-

- 

$c = 5;

$a = 4; 
$b = -

- +  
$a = 4;
echo $b;
```

Is equivalent to https://3v4l.org/4TXOI:

```php
-( -($c = 5));

$a = 4; 
$b = -( -( +($a = 4)));
echo $b;
```

Output `4`

This becomes more obvious when another minus sign is add https://3v4l.org/dvWfq:

```php
$b = -
-
- +  
$a = 4;
echo $b;
```

Becomes https://3v4l.org/8Rufb:

```php
$b = -( -( -( +($a = 4))));
echo $b;
```

Output `-4`